# What should be used: "you got it" or "you get it"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, questions

When I sent a mail to a person and he's on chat right there. What should I ask, "You got it?" or "You get it?"

Comment: _Did you get it?_

Comment: @BarrieEngland what if I say "You get it?" similar to when some one gifts someone and ask "you like it?"

Comment: _Get_ and _like_ are different kinds of verb. _Get_ describes a single action, while _like_ describes a continuing state. All sorts of things might be said between native speakers, but a non-native speaker would need to be highly confident and highly competent before departing from _Did you get it?_

Comment: *Have you got it?* works equally as well as *Did you get it?*

Comment: I would interpret "You get it?" to mean "[Did] you get it?" In other words, I'd understand you, but I'd assume you were just omitting a leading word. I would not type that to my boss, but I might type it to a close colleague.

Comment: @J.R. I agree completely. The slurring or omission of leading words in colloquial English, especially in questions, is *really* common. "Did you get it?" becomes "D'jyou get it?" becomes "You get it?" **really** easily. I doubt that any native speaker would even *notice* the omitted word in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get it? vs Got it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17488/get-it-vs-got-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colloquially, "You got it?" would be understood, but the correct sentence is "Did you get it?"

Since you are asking about a past event (as you are asking if that person received the email), you use the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask **"Did you get it?"** (if its clear you're talking about an email) or more specifically, **"Did you get my email?"**.

Also, be aware that **Do you get it?** is a colloquial way of saying **Do you understand?**