# Get it? vs Got it?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

1. > What the heck are you doing? Stop that nonsense. **Get it?**
2. > What the heck are you doing? Stop that nonsense. **Got it?**

Which one of the above is correct? Is it okay to use just "Get it?" or "Got it?" instead of "Did you get it?" or "Have you got it?" in informal spoken English?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42048/i-get-it-vs-i-got-it

Comment: @DamkerngT. But the other post is related to a statement, not a question.

Comment: That's true. And that's why I said related, not duplicated.

Comment: I also use both of them myself often enough, at least in chat rooms. In real life, when I speak, I usually add a little hint of *(Do you) get it?* and it might come out as *D'ya'get it?* while I usually omitted *Have* or *Have you* in *((Have) you) got it?* But that's just me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Get it?

- Refers to the present
- Less colloquial (and arguably less brusque)
- Could be written: **“Do you understand (now)?”**

---

> Got it?

- Refers to the past (and the present)
- More colloquial (and arguably more brusque)
- Could be written: **“Have you understood (what I just said)?”**

---

They are basically interchangeable. Some people would never say the latter because it is a bit of a departure from strict grammar and has regionally variant popularity and acceptance. You might hear them combined for emphasis, though, as in:

> Get it? Got it? Good.

Comment: In "Get it? Got it? Good" the get-it part is purely "do you understand it?" whereas the got-it part has overtones of "are you likely to **remember** it?"