# I got it = I have got it?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, american-english, formality

Someone told me " **I got it** "equals " **I have got it** "?

But why in the class I heard my teacher say: "Did you get it?"

"Do you get it?" is fine?

Comment: 'Did you get it?' means 'Did you understand what I was saying?'; 'Do you get it?' means 'Do you understand what I am saying?'

Comment: Depends on what "it" is.  If "it" is a letter I mailed to you, "Did you get it?" could mean "Did you receive it?" and the "I got it" mean "I received it".

Comment: It depends on the context of which these phrases are used.

Comment: 'I have got it' is sometimes shortened to 'I got it', eliding the 'have'. But it is something, in my estimation, far more common in America than in Britain.

Comment: Welcome to the can of worms called get in English. :) It can be very complicated. Anyway, I'd send this to the English language learners....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get it? vs Got it?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17488/get-it-vs-got-it)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So do you think that both the expressions can be used as the same in the normal context in class?